# HashMap fails for user defined objects?

Tags: java, hashmap

If I use a `HashMap` where the keys are objects of a defined class, then will the hashmap still give O(1) performance?

I think that it should not give O(1) performance because the hash key for user defined objects just returns the address of the key so there will be more collisions.

Comment: Wrong. There won't be any collisions (unless `hashCode()` is overridden) because the default implementation uses the internal address of an object, which is different for each object in the Java heap.

Comment: It really depends on your hashing algorithm.

Comment: If you plan on inserting your objects into a hashing structure (like `HashMap` or `HashSet`), you should really implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`, whose contracts are discussed in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(1)` is not exact complexity of key search in HashMap its appox.
Secondly it depends on how you define your `hashCode()` and `equals` method.

If you follow the contract that 2 equal objects have same hashcode and if objects have same hashcode then they may or may not be equal then yes you will achieve that appox. complexity of `O(1)`.

EDIT:
To maintain complexity O(1) you must provide a good hash function to have good distribution.

Comment: I think that he's implying that he didn't implement those methods, since he's saying that the `hashCode()` method returns the internal address.

Comment: following the contract doesn't necessarily mean you will keep O(1).  If they implement hashCode as `return 1;` then they keep the equals/hashcode contract but hashmap lookup turns into a linear search.

Comment: agreed. Edited my answer.